# Serilog multiple contexts filter to different files

Tags: c#, logging, serilog

I am having issue, when using multiple contexts to log to different files with Serilog

```
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                    .MinimumLevel.Debug()
                    .WriteTo.Console()
                    .WriteTo.Logger(req => req
                        .Filter.ByIncludingOnly(LoggerHelper.IsRequest)
                        .WriteTo.File($"{Configuration.GetSection("Serilog").GetSection("LogLocationFile").Value}.Requests.log", rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Day))
                    .WriteTo.Logger(req => req
                        .Filter.ByIncludingOnly(LoggerHelper.IsException)
                        .WriteTo.File($"{Configuration.GetSection("Serilog").GetSection("LogLocationFile").Value}.Exceptions.log", rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Day))
                    .WriteTo.Logger(log => log
                        .Filter.ByExcluding(e => LoggerHelper.IsRequest(e) || LoggerHelper.IsException(e))
                        .WriteTo.File($"{Configuration.GetSection("Serilog").GetSection("LogLocationFile").Value}.log", rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Day))
                    .CreateLogger();
```

For example I am using following lines to log:

```
Log.ForContext(LoggerHelper.RequestContext, "").Information(MessageTemplate, httpContext.Request.Method, httpContext.Request.Path,
            statusCode, sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds);

Log.ForContext(LoggerHelper.ExceptionContext, "").Error(MessageTemplate, "Exception", error.Code,
                error.Message,
                context?.User?.Claims.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type == Claims.ClaimInternalId)?.Value ??
                Guid.Empty.ToString());
```

LoggerHelper class as following:

```
public static class LoggerHelper
{
    public static readonly string RequestContext = "Request";
    public static readonly string ExceptionContext = "Exception";

    public static Func<LogEvent, bool> IsRequest = Matching.FromSource(RequestContext);
    public static Func<LogEvent, bool> IsException = Matching.FromSource(ExceptionContext);
}
```

When I had only 1 context, the `.ByExcluding(LoggerHelper.IsRequest)` worked correctly, but now it only logs everything to 1 file, when it should have 3 different files.

Has anyone encountered similar issue or am I missing something really simple?

Comment: The filters are applied based on the custom code you wrote on the `LoggerHelper` methods and properties - that's where the problem would be. Impossible to help more without knowing what the code for `LoggerHelper` is

Comment: I added my LoggerHelper, it's quite straight forward, since it only should check if source is matching.

Comment: Turns out I did overlooked simple thing ... ^^

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I used wrong method in this case. I need to use `Matching.WithProperty(e)` instead of `Matching.FromSource(e)` and this fixed the issue I was having.